# React and reCAPTCHA v3

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

Is there any easy way to use reCAPTCHA v3 in react? Did a google search an can only find components for v2. And only react-recaptcha-v3 for v3.

But I get an error Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js when I try to use the component.

Comment: Can you post your implementation code?

Answer (score 58):

Hey you don't need a package, its just an unnecessary package you don't need.
https://medium.com/@alexjamesdunlop/unnecessary-packages-b3623219d86
I wrote an article about why you shouldn't use it and another package.
Don't rely on some package! Rely on google instead :)

```
const handleLoaded = _ => {
  window.grecaptcha.ready(_ => {
    window.grecaptcha
      .execute("_reCAPTCHA_site_key_", { action: "homepage" })
      .then(token => {
        // ...
      })
  })
}

useEffect(() => {
  // Add reCaptcha
  const script = document.createElement("script")
  script.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=_reCAPTCHA_site_key"
  script.addEventListener("load", handleLoaded)
  document.body.appendChild(script)
}, [])

return (
  <div
    className="g-recaptcha"
    data-sitekey="_reCAPTCHA_site_key_"
    data-size="invisible"
  ></div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm trying to implement this without a package. However, it's not clear how to implement what you posted here. Where does this code go? When does it get called and how does this verify the form? There's no form in your code, I'm lost trying to understand how this code is doing anything without a form.

My understanding is v3 also requires server side calls, and I don't see any of that here. Can you please explain?

Comment: Great reply and post. Too often you find someone just linking an npm package - often doing something yourself is the best option

Comment: Many thanks for your code example. Yes, you're absolutely right. A npm package is really not necessary in this case.

Comment: Would it be possible  to share more details on how this component (it looks like you outlined a component) is used? For example : How does it integrate with each form submission, say for login or other form-related submissions? I am assuming that each of these forms will have different actions?

Comment: @YoungZaphod  
I wrote codes in `handleLoaded ` in my submit function and in `then` post form to server. Also in `UseEffect` don't write this line `script.addEventListener("load", handleLoaded)`

Comment: Great article and thanks for approaching this question with this mindset. I've almost fallen prey to using countless packages that haven't been updated in years and while seem harmless enough, could be a ticking time bomb as you update. Clearly better just to do simple stuff like this yourself.

Comment: I think this is the most easy way @FereshtehMirjalili. I read doc and they say that:
function onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
              // Add your logic to submit to your backend server here.
          });
        });
      }

Comment: There was a problem when I used it. The captcha badge remains if I change the page. I removed the script in return () => at end of useEffect. But problem still remains. I had to clear badge manually in unmount like this:
`const nodeBadge = document.querySelector(".grecaptcha-badge");
  if (nodeBadge && nodeBadge.parentNode) {
    document.body.removeChild(nodeBadge.parentNode);
  }`
and this
`const script = document.querySelector(
    'script[src^="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases"]'
  );
  if (script) {
    script.remove();
  }`

Comment: The main problem is gone but still I have a invisible grecaptcha-badge tag.

Answer (score 6):

I am teaching myself React + TypeScript and this is what I came up with to implement recaptcha v3.

I wanted a simple solution that would allow me to:

- get the token dynamically only when the form is submitted to avoid timeouts and duplicate token errors
- use recaptcha only on some components for privacy reasons (eg. login, register, forgot-password) instead of globally defining recaptcha api.js in index.html
- require the least code possible to implement in a component

reCAPTCHA.ts

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        grecaptcha: any;
    }
}

export default class reCAPTCHA {
    siteKey: string;
    action: string;

    constructor(siteKey: string, action: string) {
        loadReCaptcha(siteKey);
        this.siteKey = siteKey;
        this.action = action;
    }

    async getToken(): Promise<string> {
        let token = "";
        await window.grecaptcha.execute(this.siteKey, {action: this.action})
            .then((res: string) => {
                token = res;
            })
        return token;
    }
}

const loadReCaptcha = (siteKey: string) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = `https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js?render=${siteKey}`
    document.body.appendChild(script)
}
```

To use this class declare it as a property in the component:

```
recaptcha = new reCAPTCHA((process.env.REACT_APP_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY!), "login");
```

And on form submit get the token that you need to pass to backend:

```
let token: string = await this.recaptcha.getToken();
```

To verify the token on the backend:

recaptcha.ts

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const threshold = 0.6;

export async function validateRecaptcha(recaptchaToken: string, expectedAction: string) : Promise<boolean> {
    const recaptchaSecret = process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY;
    const url = `https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${recaptchaSecret}&response=${recaptchaToken}`;
    let valid = false;
    await fetch(url, {method: 'post'})
        .then((response: { json: () => any; }) => response.json())
        .then((data: any)=> {
            valid = (data.success && data.score && data.action && data.score >= threshold && data.action === expectedAction);
        });
    return valid;
}
```

I have very limited experience with JS/TS and React but this solution does work for me. I welcome any input on improving this code.

Comment: That's nice, clean-looking code, but I don't see any React stuff. It would help if you added a simple React component that shows how you're actually using it! :)

Comment: Agreed, clean and simple! well done sir

Answer (score 4):

You can also create your own custom hook `useReCaptcha` with React (Typescript):

```
// hooks/useReCaptcha.ts

import { RECAPTCHA_KEY, RECAPTCHA_TOKEN } from 'config/config'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const showBadge = () => {
  if (!window.grecaptcha) return
  window.grecaptcha.ready(() => {
    const badge = document.getElementsByClassName('grecaptcha-badge')[0] as HTMLElement
    if (!badge) return
    badge.style.display = 'block'
    badge.style.zIndex = '1'
  })
}

const hideBadge = () => {
  if (!window.grecaptcha) return
  window.grecaptcha.ready(() => {
    const badge = document.getElementsByClassName('grecaptcha-badge')[0] as HTMLElement
    if (!badge) return
    badge.style.display = 'none'
  })
}

const useReCaptcha = (): { reCaptchaLoaded: boolean; generateReCaptchaToken: (action: string) => Promise<string> } => {
  const [reCaptchaLoaded, setReCaptchaLoaded] = useState(false)

  // Load ReCaptcha script
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' || reCaptchaLoaded) return
    if (window.grecaptcha) {
      showBadge()
      setReCaptchaLoaded(true)
      return
    }
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.async = true
    script.src = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=${RECAPTCHA_KEY}`
    script.addEventListener('load', () => {
      setReCaptchaLoaded(true)
      showBadge()
    })
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }, [reCaptchaLoaded])

  // Hide badge when unmount
  useEffect(() => hideBadge, [])

  // Get token
  const generateReCaptchaToken = (action: string): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!reCaptchaLoaded) return reject(new Error('ReCaptcha not loaded'))
      if (typeof window === 'undefined' || !window.grecaptcha) {
        setReCaptchaLoaded(false)
        return reject(new Error('ReCaptcha not loaded'))
      }
      window.grecaptcha.ready(() => {
        window.grecaptcha.execute(RECAPTCHA_KEY, { action }).then((token: string) => {
          localStorage.setItem(RECAPTCHA_TOKEN, token)
          resolve(token)
        })
      })
    })
  }

  return { reCaptchaLoaded, generateReCaptchaToken }
}

export default useReCaptcha
```

Then in the login component for example, you can call this custom hook:

```
// Login.ts

import React from 'react'
import useReCaptcha from 'hooks/useReCaptcha'

const LoginPageEmail = () => {
  const { reCaptchaLoaded, generateReCaptchaToken } = useReCaptcha()

  const login = async () => {
    await generateReCaptchaToken('login') // this will create a new token in the localStorage
    await callBackendToLogin() // get the token from the localStorage and pass this token to the backend (in the cookies or headers or parameter..)
  }

  return (
    <button disabled={!reCaptchaLoaded} onClick={login}>
      Login
    </button>
  )
}

export default LoginPageEmail
```

Comment: this is the best solution. use custom hook instead of relying on third party package

Answer (score 3):

You can use [react-google-recaptcha3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha3) npm package (size: ~5 KB)

```
npm i react-google-recaptcha3
```

Usage

```
import ReactRecaptcha3 from 'react-google-recaptcha3';

const YOUR_SITE_KEY = '';

function App() {
 // load google recaptcha3 script
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactRecaptcha3.init(YOUR_SITE_KEY).then(
      (status) => {
        console.log(status);
      }
    );
  }, [])

}
```

Now on form submit you need to generate token and then append it to your form data

```
  const submit = () => {
    const formData = { name: "John", lastname: "Doe" }
    ReactRecaptcha3.getToken().then(
      (token) => {
        console.log(token);
        formData.token = token;
        // send request to backend
        fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(formData) }).then(...)
        
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  };
```

Now in backend you need to validate token

```
const request = require('request-promise');

const secretKey = YOUR_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY;
const userIp = 'USER_IP';
request.get({
    url: `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secretKey}&response=${recaptchaToken}&remoteip=${userIp}`,
}).then((response) => {

    // If response false return error message
    if (response.success === false) {
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            error: 'Recaptcha token validation failed'
        });
    }
    // otherwise continue handling/saving form data
    next();
})
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-google-recaptcha3?file=src/App.js)

Comment: It works for me also with appcheck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one!
https://github.com/t49tran/react-google-recaptcha-v3
npm install react-google-recaptcha-v3